# When I move mouse, mouse cursor disappears and reappears. How to fix it?

Tags: 20.04, virtualization, vmware-workstation, mouse-pointer

I have created an Ubuntu VM with VMware on my Windows 10 laptop. When I move the mouse cursor in Ubuntu, it starts flickering and disappearing and reappearing.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: When you full screen it, does it work? If not then try installing Vmware tools

Comment: Also, I noticed that this mouse lag also happens with other linux OSes like Zorin OS on VMware.

Comment: I am not able to install VMware tools as install VMware tools option is greyed out.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue, Win10 host, Ubuntu 20.04.2 client, VMplayer 16.1.2 build-17966106, open-vm-tools Version: 2:11.2.5-2ubuntu1~ubuntu20.04.1 I found that the issue only happens on my second monitor, not on the laptop's monitor. Weird.

Comment: If you are using Microsoft baisc display driver, upgrade your display driver accroding to your display card and the mouse problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue this week as well at school.  I was able to fix it by doing the following:

1. In VMware go to *Edit*/*Preferences*.
2. Under the *Input* menu I changed the option for *Optimize mouse for games* to *Always*, which had been previously set to *Automatic*.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this already. Mine was also on automatic. I changed it to always and I also changed it to never, but still in both cases, it didn't work.

Comment: I would try to figure out why VMware tools won't install.   What does the Greyed out portion say?   Reinstall or Install?

Comment: you can use the following command to check to make sure it is installed.  vmware-toolbox-cmd -v

Comment: Where is "In VMware" ? VMWare Player's "Preferences" or VM's "Virtual machine settings" have no such option (Optimize mouse)

Comment: This is a poor answer. This LOCKS the mouse into the screen. When enabling this feature it feels like vmware tools is not even installed.

Answer (score 0):

In VMware go to Edit/Preferences.
Under the Input menu I changed the option for Optimize mouse for games to Always, which had been previously set to Automatic.

This solution worked for me.

Host OS : Windows 10
Guest : Kali Linux

Answer (score 0):

@Matt's answer is more of a workaround, its not a solution. Doing that solution will lock your mouse into the VM, and the performance will be bad. It feels like VMware tools was not installed at all.

The problem for me exactly that, the Intel Xe graphics driver. I was running version 27, Needed to upgrade to v30. I specifically used [this download](https://www.guru3d.com/files-get/intel-hd-graphics-driver-download-4590,19.html)

I am using a HP zfirefly zenbook G8. This comes with a nvidia graphics card and onboard Intel.

Running Vmware workstation 15
Running vmware workstation on a Windows 10 (1904)

Do the following:

1. In windows > start > "device manager" > open up "display adapters"
2. Right click the Intel Xe graphics driver, and select "uninstall device" (dont worry you will still basic monitor capabilities after uninstall).
3. Reboot
4. Install with the .exe from the link above.
5. Reboot

After reboot, I fired on my vm again, and found that the mouse problem stopped, and the VM was usable again. Can leave Optimize mouse settings for gaming as default (Automatic).

**What do I do if you have a different graphics driver?**

Probably the same thing, Upgrade the driver. Need to do research about it though, find make a model, and find out if there are any updates out there. Uninstall old, then install new.